# CodeIgniter Session Error - Unlink Operation not Permitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm trying to debug this CodeIgniter issue I am having with my application.  I cannot figure it out so I was wondering if anyone else has come across this and could shed some light on it?

This occurs randomly when a user is logged in.  The user could be browsing and all of a sudden this error pops up.  Refresh the browser and it's gone.

CodeIgniter 3

Thanks!

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(/tmp/ci_session0189a7f1c86eb18fb70afcfedc2d5040e9c23146): Operation not permitted

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 346

Backtrace:

File: /home/*****/public_html/application/controllers/User.php
Line: 5
Function: __construct

File: /home/*****/public_html/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

Comment: I'm not positive, but I believe it's a bug in CI3. I had the same problem until I switched to the session database driver. You might want to open a issue ticket on the CI [github repo](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm pretty sure I fixed it by setting the necessary variable in my config file.  Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 40):

After doing some more research I found the issue and the answer.

In the **config.php** file you MUST set `sess_save_path` to a valid path.  It was initially set to NULL.  I have mine set to:

```
 $config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

Now the sessions are being saved in this folder and can be unlinked when needed to.

Comment: if you create a folder 'sessions' and put it in your application folder you can use this: $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'/sessions';

Comment: My problem was intermittent so I don't know how to test this, other than waiting it out.

Comment: I am having the same issues, I have done that yet it is coming maybe permission issues on my server????

Comment: Not have how I to know if is functional, but a lot of thank, I just have to wait the errors appear

Comment: I'm getting this error occasionally I've tried this same as @Ben you found any way to test this?

Answer (score 8):

I change on "application/config/config.php" :

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

To:

```
 $config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache'; (or another folder)
```

location folder "cache" is "application/cache".

Answer (score 6):

```
change application > config > config.php

$config['sess_save_path'] =  BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation to your code? This popped up in the review queue, as code-only answers tend to.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this path `application/config/config.php`
Find in this `file sess_save_path` and then replace this:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
```

with the following line:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```