# CodeIgniter CI Session Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Am using CodeIgniter for my application, my application working fine, but after sometime, when I reload any page than am getting ci_session error.

Please any one help me to solve this issue...

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: unlink(/tmp/ci_session074b4d178c387273e3eee244a10cdbafce7e337e
>       [function.unlink]: Operation not permitted
>
> Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 371
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /home/applic/public_html/workshop/application/controllers/Reports.php
>
> Line: 7
>
> Function: __construct
>
> File: /home/applic/public_html/workshop/index.php
>
> Line: 292
>
> Function: require_once

Comment: add your code as well

Comment: what code, when I load any page after sometime application display this error.

Comment: Session code where you have used

Comment: i guess there was a change of ownership of that session file in your /tmp/ directory, can you check the owner?

Comment: check application/config/config.php starting around line 326 . Confirm the expiration etc. Also see if you have session match ip as true - that can cause issues for a connections that reset the ip .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Session Error - Unlink Operation not Permitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278597/codeigniter-session-error-unlink-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Read the link sparky posted, also i commented on the answer with another way to set the folder.

Comment: Could you edit your question with your session code from config.php

Answer (score 0):

In the config.php file you MUST set sess_save_path to a valid path. It was initially set to NULL.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/';
```

if you create a folder 'sessions' and put it in your application folder you can use this:

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'/sessions'
```